# Python Statespace Calculation from Transfer Function

Tags: python, matlab, state-space, transfer-function

I have a simple transfer function in Matlab, i.e.:

```
num = [1,2,3]

den = [300,5000,80000]

sys_tf = tf(num,den)
```

then, I transform sys_tf into statespace form as;

```
sys_ss = ss(sys_tf)
```

The resulting system consists of;

```
>> sys_ss.A = [-16.67, -16.67;16, 0]     

>> sys_ss.B = [0.25;0]  

>> sys_ss.C = [-0.1956, -0.2197]

>> sys_ss.D = [0.003333]
```

On the other hand, when I create the same transfer function in Python and transform it to statespace form using "ss" command that is available in Control Systems Library (Matlab Compatibility module), I obtain a different results than what I get from Matlab as;

```
from control.matlab import ss

sys_ss = ss(num,den)

>> sys_ss.A =  [-16.67, -266.667;1,0]

>> sys_ss.B =  [1;0]  

>> sys_ss.C =  [-0.0488, -0.8788]  

>> sys_ss.D =  [0.003333]
```

The result I get from Python is same as Matlab's "*tf2ss*" command. However, I would like to get the same results in Python as I use Matlab's (*ss*) function as shown above.

Can someone help me out? What important aspect am I missing here? How do I get the same results?